# Update component data from the template

Tags: vue.js

Not too sure what is wrong here, it seems fine to me! I'm simply trying to update the data property `display` to true when I click the input within my component.

I have passed the data to the slot scope, so can't see that being the issue. It just simply won't update, using a function to toggle it works, however not what I really want to do, seems pointless.

```
<time-select>
    <div slot-scope="{ time }" class="is-inline-block">
        <label for="businessHoursTimeFrom"><i class="fas fa-clock"></i> From</label>
        <input type="text" name="businessHoursTimeFrom[]" v-model="time" v-on:click="display = true">
    </div>
</time-select>
```

The code behind:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <p>{{ display }}</p>
        <slot :time="time" :display="display"></slot>
        <div class="picker" v-if="display">
            <p>Test</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        props: [],
        data: function () {
            return {
                time: '',
                display: false
            }
        },
        mounted() {

        },
        methods: {

        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Where do you actually change display ?

Comment: @Badgy woops, sorry I copied some older code. Updated now